My solverConfig is error in class Move when use solverConfig with tabu Search
I have been trying to create a solver configration file but it has given me this error:

My solverConfig is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    <solutionClass>org.acme.foodpackaging.domain.PackagingSchedule</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>org.acme.foodpackaging.domain.Job</entityClass>
    <entityClass>org.acme.foodpackaging.domain.Line</entityClass>

    <!-- Define the score function -->
    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <constraintProviderClass>org.acme.foodpackaging.solver.FoodPackagingConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <!-- Configuração do algoritmo de busca -->
    <!--termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>30</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination-->

    <!-- Configuração do First-Fit -->
    <!--constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic-->

    <!-- Configuração do Tabu Search -->
    <localSearch>
        <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
    </localSearch>

<!--    <localSearch>-->
<!--        <localSearchType>SIMULATED_ANNEALING</localSearchType>-->
<!--    </localSearch>-->
</solver>

I looked for an example with a solverConfig but there is none, I have one but it was similar to Optaplanner, could you help me with this issue? The example I'm using is FoodPacking

From your solver config, I see that you have disabled construction heuristics. This means that Local Search starts with an uninitialized solution. A situation that must never happen.
The solution to your problem is to put a construction heuristic back in. But there is still a small bug in there - because Local Search should have detected this situation, and failed with a much better exception. We'll address that.
